# Add elements whose attribute is equal to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is add the elements whose attribute `'data-date'` is the same as the current date to a div that is named today. I'd appreciate your help.

```
var fechasIguales = fechaInicioPartido == fechaActual;

if (fechasIguales = true){

$('.Aquí').append(element.getAttribute('data-date') === fechaActual.getDate() ()); 

/*
  Here, above this comment is where I believe I am wrong, I can not give the elements.
  If I put this code, all the elements are added.

    $('.Aquí').append(element);

  And it's not what I want.
*/
```

Comment: `if (fechasIguales = true){` is performing an assignment and is always `true`.

Comment: i assume that it's the 3x=, try 2x= (`==`)

Comment: do `if (fechasIguales == true)` this will perform a comparison; you can also do `if (fechasIguales)` for short-hand and it will default compare it to the `true` value.

Comment: What is `fetchaActual`? A Date? A string? Also, give us an example of what the value of `'data-date'` is. Finally, The code you have in `append` is just wrong. You'll want to look into [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) for how to get elements that match certain criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the issue [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) mentioned, you can retrieve the attribute using jQuery's .attr() function and check if the element is the one you are looking for then append it.

```
...
if($(element).attr('data-date') == fechaActual.getDate()) {
  $('.Aqui').append($(element));
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class="date-team" data-date="13-02-2017 14:45">

var fechaActual= new Date();

var fechaInicioPartido = element.getAttribute('data-date')
var fechasIguales = fechaInicioPartido == fechaActual;

if (fechasIguales = true){

$('.Aquí').append(element.getAttribute('data-date') === fechaActual()); 

/*
```

Here, above this comment is where I believe I am wrong, I can not give the elements.